On the equality of two integrals up to a set of zero measure.
Let $[a,b]$ be a (finite) interval, $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure and $C\subseteq [a,b]$ be a measurable set. We consider a function $f\in L^1[a,b]$. We let consider the set $(a,b)\setminus C$ then results:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_C f\; d\lambda&=&\int_{[a,b]} f\;d\lambda-\int_{[a,b]\setminus C}f\; d\lambda\\
&\color{red}{=}&\int_{[a,b]}f\;d\lambda-\int_{(a,b)\setminus C}f\;d\lambda
\end{eqnarray*}
I have a doubt about equality in red: we have then that $$\int_{[a,b]\setminus C}f\;d\lambda=\int_{(a,b)\setminus C}f\;d\lambda\tag1$$
We ask ourselves if $(1)$ is true, the answer I have to say is yes, since we have that: $$[a,b]\setminus C=[\{a\}\setminus C]\cup [\{b\}\setminus C]\cup [(a,b)\setminus C],$$ where the union is clearly disjoined. Now we have that $\{a\}\setminus C$ it is either the empty set if $a\in C$  or $\{a\}$ if $a\notin C$, in any case $\{a\}\setminus C$ is a $\lambda-$null set, in the same way one can reason for $\{b\}\setminus C$.

Is the motivation correct? Or can something else be done or observed, or does equality (1) not hold? Thanks!


Correct! More succintly, since $[a,b]\setminus C$ is the disjoint union of $(a,b)\setminus C$ and ${a,b}\setminus C$, we certainly have $$\int_{[a,b]\setminus C}f;d\lambda=\int_{(a,b)\setminus C}f;d\lambda+\int_{{a,b}\setminus C}f;d\lambda;$$but ${a,b}\setminus C$ is a subset of the measure-$0$ set ${a,b}$ and thus itself has measure $0$, and so $\int_{{a,b}\setminus C}f;d\lambda=0$.
